# How to write LINQ to generate SQL with CONTAINS keyword

Tags: sql, oracle, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I am using EF to connect with Oracle database and writing a linq query like this

```
 var keyword = this.Keywords.ToLower();
 var filteredItems = from item in active_items 
                     where item.Name.Contains(keyword)
                     select item;
```

The generated SQL from linq makes use of Like and keyword wrapped in %% signs.

```
e.g. WHERE "EXTENT1"."NAME" LIKE '%keyword%'
```

Which seems OK but I need the sql to make use "Contains" keyword and need the SQL to be like

```
e.g. WHERE CONTAINS(NAME,'keyword') > 0
```

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First option:
use devart library: http://blog.devart.com/using-oracle-full-text-search-in-entity-framework.html

Second option:
make a stored procedure in oracle that receive your keyword and search it and map the procedure into your model (if you are using model-first)

Third option:
in the linq mapping use a function like INSTR.  See http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/win.112/e18754/canonical_map.htm#ODPNT7777

Comment: Thanks Daniel: Can you please elaborate 3rd option as I may not be able to implement options 1 or 2. How to use function like INSTR?

Comment: Rahul, you must add a reference to the System.Data.Entity and call EntityFunction.Contains in your query.  Right now I don't have an Oracle machine to make a complete example, but you can see an example here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456873(v=vs.110).aspx.  I think you need Oracle Data Provider for .NET: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2011/11-sep/o51odt-453447.html

Comment: I went with the second option. However calling a stored proc in Oracle from EF isn't as simple as in Microsoft SQL server but made my way through. Thanks for suggestions.